# how to call an array which is in a function from the another function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js

This is the async function:

```
async function getpackages(conn, childId, callback) {
    var childId = childId;
     var request6 = new sql.Request(conn);
     var packageQuery = "select OrderId,ChildID from dbo.tbl_Scheduler where NoOfMealsLeft>0 and ChildId=" + childId;
     await request6.query(packageQuery, function (err, packagelist) {
         if (!err && packagelist.recordsets.length > 0) {
             console.log("Error:" + err + "Result:" + util.inspect(packagelist.recordsets[0]));
             var orderdetail_ = [];
             for (i = 0; i < packagelist.recordsets[0].length; i++) {
                 orderdetail_.push(packagelist.recordsets[0][i].OrderId);
             }
             console.log("-->" + orderdetail_);
             callback(null, packagelist.recordsets[0]);
        } else if (packagelist.recordsets.length < 1) {
            callback("Not a valid id input", null);
        }
    });
};
```

I need to call the `orderdetails_` array in the query.  The array contains four data and I need to iterate over 4 data one by one, using the or in the SQL query.

```
module.exports.newscheduledmeal = function (req, res, next, callback) {
    let entered_date = req.query.date;
    let childId = req.query.id;
    let current_date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    if (entered_date < current_date) {
        return callback('Please enter date more than or equal to current date.', null);
    } else
        var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);

    try {
        conn.connect().then(function () {
            var request = new sql.Request(conn);
            getpackages(conn, childId, function (err, orderid) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null);
                } else
                    var PackageidQuery = "select PackageId from dbo.tbl_Order where OrderId=";

                request.query(PackageidQuery, function (err, packagelist) {
                    if (!err) {
                        conn.close();
                        callback(null, packagelist.recordsets);
                    } else {
                        conn.close();
                        callback("Error", null);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Exception occured:" + err);
        conn.close();
        callback(err, null);
    }
};
```

I want to get the details of the array which is in `getpackages` to be used in the module section and specifically in the SQL query section.

Comment: your question is about async result in js, it was already discussed, see i.e. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: ok let me see plz

Comment: can you help me more specifically

Comment: okay, how do you call `newscheduledmeal`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: i did that myself using another function